# Displaying dynamic text from layer other than index on Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

For a map project I am working on with Data Driven Pages, I'd like to create a dynamic text using information from a different layer than my index layer.

Is this possible?
Any add ins or extensions available to make this happen?

Comment: This works great but if the join fields are named the same, be sure to alias one of them as something different or data driven pages gets confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly add dynamic text from a layer other than your Index Layer to a map layout.  A way to work around this would be to do a Join.

You could join the layer you want to label to your Index Layer.  This join could be based based on location or an attribute.  Then you could use using the "Data Drive Page Attribute" option under "Page Text."

(If you want to add labels inside your Data Frame, you can use the regular "Label Features" tool.  I'm assuming you want to add text outside of your data frame or as part of a title block).